# Code added after URL (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

My site (built in Wordpress) , has a problem in all the URLs - a suffix always appears "?v= (code)".

http://www.carvalhocustom.com/

Already deactivated all plugins and changed the theme back to Twenty Fourteen, but the problem remains . Any tips ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It was an option in woocomerce regarding cached  Geolocation.